# Data exchange between pages without usin Session,ViewState,Cookie,QueryString

Tags: c#, .net, session, cookies

I am trying to data transport beetween pages with session,viewstate,cookie but data is wents to null. 
I want to make data exchange between pages without using Session,ViewState,Cookie,QueryString.

How can I do?

Comment: Could you elaborate why something like Session or querystring doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yes, more detail is definitely needed.  Can we assume you are using ASP.NET web forms since you are trying to use ViewState?  As bartimar said, providing a code sample would help enormously too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's an idea to explain what you're trying to do, so someone can happily sugest what to fix in order to get sessions, etc. to work..

But to get back to what you're questioning, if you can't POST/GET use session or cookies. Maybe you should use JavaScript and not change pages but manipulate the DOM to hide/display stuff..